# Filter users with select, then update one of their attributes

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to look for AD users who have a `Null` attribute `terminalservicesprofilepath`, and to update this attribute in the same command.

I can select the users, but how to update the attribute "on the fly"?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(ObjectClass -eq "user") -and (Enabled -eq $true)} -server $DC[1] -Properties * | select SAMAccountName,displayName,DistinguishedName,Mail,Homemdb,@{Name="TSP";Expression={([adsi]("LDAP://$($_.distinguishedName)")).psbase.InvokeGet("terminalservicesprofilepath")}} | where {($_.DistinguishedName -match ".OU=USERS.") -and ($_.TSP -eq $null)}
```

Comment: if you can use quest active roles for AD this might help you: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/f/4834/t/19569166

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [Hey, Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/10/23/how-can-i-edit-terminal-server-profiles-for-users-in-active-directory.aspx)

I think you can do:

```
([adsi]("LDAP://$($_.distinguishedName)")).psbase.InvokeSet("terminalservicesprofilepath",$newPath)
```

You would just need to pip that command in after the initial lookup, and then do a SetInfo().

Probably would be easiest if, like in the blog post, you run your initial Get-ADUser into a variable, so you can work with the objects in it:

```
$users = "huge Get-ADUser command"
foreach ($u in $users)
{
    $foo = [ADSI]("LDAP://$u.DistinguishedName")
    $foo.psbase.InvokeSet("terminalservicesprofilepath",$newPath)
    $foo.SetInfo()
}
```